# Deleting rows with conditions from entire dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with mix numeric scale values and other continuous values. However, the missing data represented by the following values -1 and 8. this is an example:

```
df = data.frame(Name = c('George','Andrea', 'Micheal','Maggie','Ravi','Xien','Jalpa'), 
                 Grade_score=c(4,6,2,9,5,7,8),
                 Mathematics1_score=c(45,78,44,89,66,49,72),
                 Science_score=c(-1,52,45,88,-1,90,47),
                 Science_scale=c(-1,5,5,8,3,0,7))
```

I want to delete any row that has any of the missing data from the entire data.frame.
I can do it column by column but I have more than 25 columns.

```
df2<-subset(df, df$x1 !="-1")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%  
  filter(if_all(everything(), ~ !(.x %in% c(-1, 8))))

# A tibble: 3 × 5
  Name    Grade_score Mathematics1_score Science_score Science_scale
  <chr>         <dbl>              <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1 Andrea            6                 78            52             5
2 Micheal           2                 44            45             5
3 Xien              7                 49            90             0
```

Answer (score 2):

A one liner using base R:

```
df[apply(df[,-1],1, \(x) !any(x %in% c(-1,8))),]
```

Or, you can convert to `NA` and use `na.omit()`

```
library(dplyr)  
df %>% 
  mutate(across(-Name, ~if_else(.x %in% c(-1,8),NA_real_,.x))) %>% 
  na.omit()
```

Output:

```
      Name Grade_score Mathematics1_score Science_score Science_scale
    <char>       <num>              <num>         <num>         <num>
1:  Andrea           6                 78            52             5
2: Micheal           2                 44            45             5
3:    Xien           7                 49            90             0
```

Answer (score 2):

### base R

```r
df[rowSums(sapply(df, `%in%`, c(-1, 8))) < 1,]
#      Name Grade_score Mathematics1_score Science_score Science_scale
# 2  Andrea           6                 78            52             5
# 3 Micheal           2                 44            45             5
# 6    Xien           7                 49            90             0
```

### dplyr

(While TomHoel's answer shows this as well, edited after I started drafting this, I'll keep it due to my discussion of multiple-standards in the note.)

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(if_all(everything(), ~ !. %in% c(-1, 8)))
#      Name Grade_score Mathematics1_score Science_score Science_scale
# 1  Andrea           6                 78            52             5
# 2 Micheal           2                 44            45             5
# 3    Xien           7                 49            90             0
```

---

Note: if the `Grade_score` column should not be filtered out for `8` values (since that seems to be on the same scale as the others), then we can split the logic:

```r
df %>%
  filter(
    if_all(-Grade_score, ~ !. %in% c(-1, 8)),
    Grade_score != -1
  )
#      Name Grade_score Mathematics1_score Science_score Science_scale
# 1  Andrea           6                 78            52             5
# 2 Micheal           2                 44            45             5
# 3    Xien           7                 49            90             0
# 4   Jalpa           8                 72            47             7
```

If you have multiple such columns, then we can do

```r
df %>%
  filter(
    if_all(-c(Grade_score, Science_scale), ~ !. %in% c(-1, 8)), 
    if_all(c(Grade_score, Science_scale), ~ . != -1)
  )
#      Name Grade_score Mathematics1_score Science_score Science_scale
# 1  Andrea           6                 78            52             5
# 2 Micheal           2                 44            45             5
# 3  Maggie           9                 89            88             8
# 4    Xien           7                 49            90             0
# 5   Jalpa           8                 72            47             7
```

and the base R variant, keeping the use of `` `%in%` `` for convenience only.

```r
df[rowSums(cbind(
  sapply(df[,-c(1:2, 5)], `%in%`, c(-1, 8)),
  sapply(df[,c(1:2, 5)], `%in%`, -1))) < 1,]
#      Name Grade_score Mathematics1_score Science_score Science_scale
# 2  Andrea           6                 78            52             5
# 3 Micheal           2                 44            45             5
# 4  Maggie           9                 89            88             8
# 6    Xien           7                 49            90             0
# 7   Jalpa           8                 72            47             7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option for base R. We can replace the values you want with NA for the full dataset and then just omit all the rows with NA.

```r
na.omit(replace(df, df ==-1 | df == 8, NA))
#>      Name Grade_score Mathematics1_score Science_score Science_scale
#> 2  Andrea           6                 78            52             5
#> 3 Micheal           2                 44            45             5
#> 6    Xien           7                 49            90             0
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `apply` beware of conversions to character in frames with character and/or numeric, since it may introduce leading/trailing spaces (apply expects and converts to matrices which can only hold one data class/type).

Since

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) grep(8, x, value = T))
$Name
character(0)

$Grade_score
[1] "8"

$Mathematics1_score
[1] "78" "89"

$Science_score
[1] "88"

$Science_scale
[1] " 8"               # <-------- " 8" will make direct comparisons FALSE
```

either use `trimws`

```
df[!apply(df, 1, function(x) any(trimws(x) %in% c(-1, 8))), ]
     Name Grade_score Mathematics1_score Science_score Science_scale
2  Andrea           6                 78            52             5
3 Micheal           2                 44            45             5
6    Xien           7                 49            90             0
```

or use, as pointed out by the other answers, `apply` without character columns (may be difficult to find/see/know in some cases!) `sapply`/`lapply` or libraries like `dplyr`